# php - It is possible to merge more than two of 2d array that have different element number?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, array-merge

I have 3 set of 2d array that have different element number?One is the array that need to be as key(date and time) to compare with other two array.The other two array must in sequence.For row that empty, i want set as -9999.

First array :

```
Array (   
       [0] => Array
          (
            [0] => 01/7/2013
            [1] => 12.00 a.m

          )

       [1] => Array
          (
            [0] => 01/7/2013
            [1] => 12.01 a.m

          )

       [2] => Array
          (
            [0] => 01/7/2013
            [1] => 12.02 a.m

          )

      )
```

For second array:

```
Array(   

   [0] => Array
       (
          [0] => 01/7/2013
          [1] => 12.01 a.m
          [2] => 9.02
       )
 )
```

For Third array:

```
 Array(   
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01/7/2013
            [1] => 12.00 a.m
            [2] => 1.23
            [3] => 6.1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01/7/2013
            [1] => 12.02 a.m
            [2] => 1.75
            [3] => 1.75
        )

  )
```

and i need the output as:

```
Array(   
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01/7/2013
            [1] => 12.00 a.m
            [2] => -9999
            [3] => 1.23
            [4] => 6.1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01/7/2013
            [1] => 12.01 a.m
            [2] => 9.02
            [3] => -9999
            [4] => -9999
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01/7/2013
            [1] => 12.02 a.m
            [2] => -9999
            [3] => 1.75
            [4] => 1.75
        )
 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
$out = array();
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    $date = explode('/', $value[0]);//Change date format
    $dex = strtotime($date[1].'/'.$date[0].'/'.$date[2].' '.$value[1]);
    $head = (array_key_exists($dex, $out)) ? $out[$dex] : array_slice($value, 0, 2);
    $out[$dex] = array_merge($head, array_slice($value, 2));
    $cnt = ($cnt > count($out[$dex])) ? $cnt : count($out[$dex]);
}
$out = array_map(function ($e) use ($cnt){
    return array_pad($e, $cnt, '-9999');
}, array_values($out));
print_r($out);
```

That works for PHP 5.3 and later. For older versions of PHP, you can replace the `array_map` function with the following:

```
foreach ($out as $key => $value){
    $res[] = array_pad($value, $cnt, -9999);
}
print_r($res);
```

**NEW VERSION** (for PHP 5.3 or later):

```
$template = array();
array_walk($arr1, function (&$e, $k) use (&$template){
    $date = explode('/', $e[0]);
    $dex = strtotime($date[1].'/'.$date[0].'/'.$date[2].' '.$e[1]);
    $template[$dex][0] = '-9999';
});
$arr1 = array_combine(array_keys($template), $arr1);
$out = array();
$data = array($arr2, $arr3);
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2){
        $date = explode('/', $value2[0]);//Change date format
        $dex = strtotime($date[1].'/'.$date[0].'/'.$date[2].' '.$value2[1]);
        $out[$key][$dex] = array_slice($value2, 2);
    }
    $out[$key] += array_diff_key($template, $out[$key]);
    foreach ($out[$key] as $key2 => $value2){
        $arr1[$key2] = array_merge($arr1[$key2], $value2);
    }
}
print_r(array_values($arr1));
```

Comment: Good try. Can you reduce this code. 6 foreach loops. OMG!!!

Comment: @PédeLeão can you explain this line:                               $head = (array_key_exists($dex, $out)) ? $out[$dex] : array_slice($value, 0, 2);                                               because i get an error:                                                Warning:array_key_exists():The first argument should be either a string or an integer in... i noticed this error come out if the date is more than 12 days of that month,means 13-31/month/year range day date will get this error.

Comment: @PédeLeão $dex will give output all data in column first and second right?which means date and time. i'm stuck now because doen't know where is the fault since its only not working for date 13th onwards.. 1-12 ok. any idea?

Comment: Hi @PédeLeão, sorry for disturbing you again.but have issue come out for that code.let say second array does not have value on 12.00a.m, and third array have value on 12 a.m;it just display the 3rd array first then replace last column in 12a.m with -9999.its not right because i need it in sequence.i have edit my arrays above so you can see the logic.hope you can help me on this.

Comment: @PédeLeão the code above will generate output in 12a.m as                                                                         [0] => 01/7/2013
            [1] => 12.00 a.m
            [2] => 1.23
            [3] => 6.1
            [4] => -9999   instead what i need.

Comment: i hope u can spend time with my request @PédeLeão. i'm stuck.i hv tried to modify your code,but still not get the correct answer.

Comment: @PédeLeão thanks for your time.suddenly i get idea to combine your code and Jack [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737482/php-how-to-merge-2d-array-that-have-different-no-of-element-for-each-array) and improve it and its working just like i want now. i already updated the answer above its may usefull for others. =)